# how to get text in a div without an id or class jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

i have the follow problem. I want to parse a html page with jsoup. The parsing is not the problem but i need to get the text in a div without using the id or class. there is a custom attribute in the div element.

```
<div id="test" custom="tester">Get this text </div>
```

i tried the follow thing:

```
Element bedrijfwrapper = document.select("custom[name="tester"].first();
```

but i dont't get it to work. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
doc.select("div[custom=tester]")
```

Comment: i don't know why you are down but this works perfect

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
document.select('[custom="tester"]').first();
```

Good luck.